# Is a finite volume with infinite extension possible with curvature of space?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

Let's assume a general spherically symmetric spacetime. The metric is
$$\mathrm{d}s^2=-Bc^2 \mathrm{d}t^2+A \mathrm{d}r^2+r^2 \mathrm{d}\Omega.$$

and a spherical volume in that metric will be calculated with
$$V = 4\pi\int_0^Rr^2\sqrt{|A|}\ \mathrm{d}r.$$

Therefore, it should be possible to construct a theoretical metric which is infinite in extension ($R$ can take every, arbitrarily large value) — but finite in volume. One only has to "tune" the curvature parameter A such that  $\sqrt{|A|}$ decreases at least with $1/r^3$ for the integral to converge.

Is there any mistake in this reasoning (especially in GR) or is it therefore correct to say that it is possible to construct a metric in GR which leads to a finite volume with infinite extension?

Comment: The volume formula stems from another question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/680076/

Comment: No need for the GR machinery, just look at [Gabriel's Horn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel%27s_horn) to see that it is possible. It is nonetheless easy to construct the metric for the plain Horn.

Comment: The question is dedicated to GR, whether *there* something speaks agains such a construction

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any mistake in this reasoning (especially in GR) or is it therefore correct to say that it is possible to construct a metric in GR which leads to a finite volume with infinite extension?

It is possible but only in the universe with negative masses.

In case of static spherically symmetric spacetime filled with matter of density $\rho$ the proper volume reads:

\begin{equation}
V(r)=\int_{0}^{r}\tilde{r}^2~\Big(1-\frac{\kappa c^2}{\tilde{r}}\int_{0}^{\tilde{r}}~\rho(x)~x^2~dx\Big)^{-1/2}~d\tilde{r} \tag{1}, ~~~~~\kappa\equiv \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}
\end{equation}

The derivative of $V'(r)$ goes asymptotically to zero (constant proper volume) only if the density there is negative and proportional to $r^{-(3+\epsilon)}$ ($\epsilon \geq 0$).

Comment: Why is "negative density" an evidence for "not possible"?

Comment: @BarrielRemoval, negative density means negative energy or negative mass. To my knowledge there is no evidence for such matter in the known universe.

Comment: No evidence yet, but its existence is discussed: https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018A%26A...620A..92F/abstract

Comment: Let's make a compromise: "finite volume with infinite extension would be possible with negative energy density"

Comment: @BarrierRemoval, no compromises, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: It's not really "corrected"... The universe doesn't need to have negative masses to live in a space which has negative energy density

Comment: Negative energy means negative mass. But maybe you mean something else. See https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20200000366/downloads/20200000366.pdf .

Comment: Wow, thanks for the cool script and the markings! That's worth an own question...

Comment: I do not understand, could you download that pdf presentation?

Comment: This question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702073/how-is-electric-charge-acting-as-a-negative-mass-in-general-relativity

Answer (score 0):

What you say is correct, but it's also not really meaningful.
Whether the coordinate description is bounded or not can be changed arbitrarily, the physically meaningful distinction is whether the manifold itself has a finite volume or not.

Consider a 1D manifold with a finite volume: $x \in (-1, 1)$ with the Euclidean metric.
Now, let us map this to $y \in (-\infty, \infty)$: we can do so with the inverse hyperbolic tangent, $y = \tanh^{-1}{x}$.
This manifold will have a nontrivial metric $g_{yy} = (\mathrm{d}x / \mathrm{d}y)^2 = (1 - \tanh^2y)^2$, but the total volume must be unchanged: indeed, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{g_{yy}} \mathrm{d}y = 2 = \int_{-1}^{1} \mathrm{d} x$.

We now have a manifold with finite volume and two equivalent coordinate descriptions, one bounded and the other unbounded.
I hope this illustrates the fact that the boundedness of coordinates is not physical, it's just an artifact of how we describe the manifold.

For a GR example (of the inverse of what you say) see [Penrose diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_diagram): they can represent an unbounded spacetime with bounded coordinates.

Comment: I do not mean to find a cool way playing around with coordinates that the thing *looks* infinite as the way of the runner fighting against the turtle in the example of archimedes. I meant that it *is* infinite independent of coordinates. - - You can find infinite coordinates if something is finite, you proved with your example. - - - However, is it possible to find finite coordinates for something which *is* infinite? It isn't. - - - The manifold *itself* is meant to be infinite in extension but finite in volume. - The description with A and B is meant to find the simplest, plain, coordinates

Comment: Got to correct a mistake: The story was told by Zenon of Elea and the runner was Achilles.