# What is the evidence that gravitational fields don't sum up as a superposition?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, non-linear-systems

Einstein's field equations are non-linear. Gravity gravitates (self-interacts). It's very complicated to solve Einstein's field equations for more than one central object. That are keystones in general relativity.

It's hard to imagine though. Is there (experimental?) evidence that space-times surrounding massive objects (metric tensors) do not just sum up as a superposition (like electric fields do)?

Comment: 1. What do you mean "regarded as non-linear"? Whether an equation is linear or not is a fact, not a matter of how we regard it. 2. How is this not just asking for [experimental evidence for general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity) in general? The Einstein equations are central to GR - if their non-linearity was wrong, then their predictions would be wrong, too.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/706262/2451

Comment: @ACuriousMind: 1. Ok, but I should also see it in experiments, not _only_ in the equations. 2. It's totally different. Experimental evidence for GR is for example perihelion of mercury, but therefore, you do not need any superposition of spacetimes. My question is only about superposition, not about GR in general.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Addendum for 1. Why are they non-linear (why is that "a fact"?) Please, could you explain that step-by-step, for a beginner, I really just want to understand. Addendum for 2. Their predictions are made without any superposition, aren't they?

Comment: @Qmechanic: related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/701716/is-a-finite-volume-with-infinite-extension-possible-with-curvature-of-space

Comment: 1. The Einstein tensor (the quantity that appears in the Einstein equations) is simply a non-linear function of the metric. If you do not understand what that means, you have to be more precise about *what* you don't understand about that.

Comment: 2. Asking "only about superposition" supposes that you can somehow remove the non-linearity from GR while leaving at least something intact - but "GR without non-linearity" is not a well-defined theory without further elaboration. You *could* ask things like "Which observations cannot be explained by [linearized gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity)?", but whether you mean *that* is exactly the thing I'm asking you to clarify.

Comment: 1. And how about the Ricci curvature tensor, is that also a non-linear function of the metric?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Sorry, linearized Gravity is _not_ what I mean with my question. Only the name is similar, but the concept is totally different. I'm talking about a _superposition_ of spacetimes like fields (the question is: why is it not possible?); in linearized gravity they _assume_ a flat background and calculate with pertubations on that. It's completely different from superposition of spacetimes regarded as fields.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : "... but "GR without non-linearity" is not a well-defined theory without further elaboration." ****   That is a very interesting point: Which elaboration do you mean?

Answer (score 12):

Black hole solutions would not exist in a linear theory of gravity. This is because black holes are vacuum solutions, not sourced by any matter, and there are no static vacuum solutions that die off asymptotically in a linear theory (this follows from properties of the wave equation). Therefore, observations of black holes, such as the black hole in the center of our galaxy, binary black hole mergers observed by LIGO and Virgo, and the black hole photographed by the Event Horizon telescope, are direct evidence that gravity is not described by a linear theory. Proving that black holes are a robust prediction of GR was a major accomplishment and relied crucially on non-linear aspects of the theory. Work providing theoretical and observational evidence of black holes was awarded the [2020 Nobel Prize in Physics](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2020/press-release/).

Additionally, when two black holes merge, the result is not a superposition of the metrics of two black holes, but a new black hole spacetime with a larger mass. Quasinormal modes seen in the ringdown of a binary black hole merger provide a way to observe the final state of the merger.

---

Another example is cosmology. The [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) describing the expansion of the Universe are non-linear (since they are simply Einstein's equations applied to a situation with a lot of symmetry). The standard model of cosmology based on these equations has undergone many, many observational tests, including one that won the [2011 Nobel Prize in Physics](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/physics/2011/press-release/).

---

On a different note, my unsolicited advice would be to learn what linearity and nonlinearity mean precisely in a purely mathematical setting, before asking about general relativity. These are very general concepts that can be understood with much simpler examples, and I fear that adding GR to the mix is both unnecessary and causing more confusion than clarity. For example, you may want to study why the harmonic oscillator is a linear equation, while an anharmonic oscillator is not.

Answer (score 6):

Einstein's equations are
$$
G_{\mu\nu}[g] = R_{\mu\nu}[g] - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R[g] = 8\pi G_N T_{\mu\nu} \tag{1}.
$$
where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric of the spacetime. The Ricci scalar is given by
$$
R[g] = g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu}[g].
$$
Here, $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the metric inverse of $g_{\mu\nu}$. The Ricci tensor is given by
$$
R_{\mu\nu}[g] = \partial_\lambda \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda[g] - \partial_\mu \Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\lambda}[g] + \Gamma^\lambda_{\lambda\tau}[g] \Gamma^\tau_{\mu\nu}[g] - \Gamma^\lambda_{\tau\mu}[g] \Gamma^\tau_{\nu\lambda}[g]
$$
where $\partial_\mu \equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$ and sum over repeated indices is implied ($a_\mu b^\mu \equiv \sum\limits_{\mu=0}^3 a_\mu b^\mu$).

The Christoffel symbols are further given by
$$
\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}[g] = \frac{1}{2} g^{\lambda \tau} ( \partial_\mu g_{\nu\tau} + \partial_\nu g_{\mu\tau} - \partial_\tau g_{\mu\nu} ) . 
$$

The fundamental quantity in GR is the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$. It is abundantly clear that Einstein's equations are (VERY VERY) non-linear in this variable. This is an undeniable fact about the equations - there is nothing "to be regarded as..." here.

Regarding the evidence of the "non-linearity" - literally EVERY experimental test of GR that goes beyond the Newtonian limit is precisely a test of the non-linearity of Einstein's equations.

---

I feel like OP is very confused about what linearity means and what superposition is so let me add a few words here.

A function $f(x)$ is linear in its argument
$$
f(x_1+x_2) = f(x_1)+f(x_2)
$$
Einstein's equations are NOT linear since if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are two metrics which solve (1), then $g_1+g_2$ is NOT a solution since
$$
G_{\mu\nu}[g_1+g_2] \neq G_{\mu\nu}[g_1] + G_{\mu\nu}[g_2]
$$
Superposition is about "adding solutions to obtain a new solution" and therefore it applies as a concept ONLY in linear theories. It makes no sense to talk about in a non-linear theory like GR.

Comment: Which tests do you mean with "goes beyond the Newtonian limit"?

Comment: The Newtonian limit of GR is the linear + small speed limit. Recall that Newtonian gravity is a linear theory and GR reproduces Newtonian gravity in the linear regime. Going beyond this regime is precisely where GR kicks in.

Comment: Do you mean _near_ the central mass or _far away_ from the central mass with "beyond the Newtonian limit"?

Comment: none of that. I mean "including non-linear effects" (precession of prehilia of mercury) or "include relativistic effects" (gravitational redshift or bending of light)

Comment: Ok, that means "linear" is for you the same as Newton and non-linear is "not following Newton"? But the relativistic effects could _sum up_ as a superposition, we aren't talking about that here...

Comment: linear+non-relativistic = Newtonian limit. Everything else = GR. GR is not a linear theory so superposition is not possible.

Comment: @BarrierRemoval - Edited the answer to include a few words about superpositions.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I learned a lot from it! Have to go through all these complicated equations though, but your wrinting is clear and I can take it as a map to more understanding, I really appreciate that!

Comment: I'm wondering if someone could probably please show for the Schwarzschild-metric that $R_{\mu\nu} (g_1+g_2) \neq R_{\mu\nu} (g_1)+R_{\mu\nu} (g_2)$ or whether this has been done already, probably, somewhere in the literature?

Answer (score 4):

Gravitational wave (GW) observations of binary black holes (BH) may provide experimental tests of *superposition of spacetimes*, as defined by you.

Each BH is described by a spacetime metric, but the joint field of the binary system is not the sum of the two individual spacetimes.  This is clear from the Einstein Field Equations.  It's also backed up by numerical relativity calculations, which directly solve the field equations.  The post-Newtonian expansion used to approximate the motion of inspiraling binaries also contains explicitly non-linear terms.  Effects like gravitational self-force and non-linear gravitational memory come out in the post-Newtonian expansion.

So if we measure the waveform of a binary BH system with high enough precision we can directly observe these effects.  In principle one could perform a model selection test to check if a particular non-linear post-Newtonian term should be added or dropped from a waveform model to fit LIGO data.  As pointed out by @Andrew in the comments, LIGO in fact does something very similar to this when they perform generic tests of GR.  They do an analysis that checks if the coefficients of the post-Newtonian expansion are different than what is predicted by GR.  So far LIGO has seen no significant deviation from the GR prediction, as shown in [Fig. 7 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06861).

Most of the non-linear terms are just "regular" non-linear terms in the perturbation expansion and don't have special names.  GW memory is one named effect that is about as non-linear as it gets, a GW effect generated by GWs.  It is a target for LIGO, LISA, and pulsar timing arrays, but has not been directly observed.

Comment: "I don't know if anyone has done a model selection test the check if a particular non-linear post-Newtonian term should be added or dropped from a waveform model to fit LIGO data." -- Yes, this has been done. See, eg, Fig 6-7 and Table VI here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06861

Comment: In what sense is gravitational self-force an explicitly non-linear effect? You can have a self-force in the very linear EM field. (It is of course true that even at leading order the GSF captures an important part of the nonlinear dynamics in a BH binary.)

Comment: @mment you are correct.  I edited to remove that part.